# Можно ли в Redmine создать шаблон проекта?

Tags: redmine

Подскажите, можно ли в Redmine сохранить какой-то проект в качестве шаблона и использовать его потом при создании нового схожего проекта? Чтобы не создавать какие-то вещи с 0

Comment: что мешает держать заготовку(с тегами), в текстовом файле, и при создании вставлять и редактировать задачу?

Comment: В Redmine не копируются подпроекты при копировании проекта, только задачи с подзадачами.

Answer (score 0):

есть расширения для шаблонов задач.
а шаблонные проектов, с набор задач, подзадач, с настроенным трекером и участниками я делаю так:
создал проект Шаблоны. в нем создаю разные проекты и настраиваю. затем в админке можно такие проекты копировать. вот и все.
к сожалению, только в админке, но это лучше, чем ничего